Django makemigrations not making migrations for my app
Full disclosure. This is for my github project warehauser which can be found at: https://github.com/warehauser/warehauser
If you download it and follow the INSTALL file instructions it says to
python manage.py makemigrations

But when that is done it does not make the migrations for the core app. 'core' is included in the warehauser/settings.oy INSTALLED_APPS setting. The 'core' app/directory is in the project base directory.
If I go:
python manage.py makemigrations core

It picks up the core app and makes the migrations. But I want to know why it is not working without specifying the core app explicitly.
I attempted:
(venv) D:\project\warehauser\>python manage.py makemigrations

And expected that to include making migrations for core app.
I attempted:
(venv) D:\project\warehauser\>python manage.py makemigrations core

And that worked. But I need the first command to work for the core app.

check INSTALLED_APPS

I have and the core app is there. As per https://github.com/warehauser/warehauser/blob/master/warehauser/settings.py

I don't know why it's happened to you, but try this in you INSTALLED_APPS:
'core.apps.CoreConfig'


While that worked, I would prefer to know why just having 'core', does not work. Thanks for the pointer anyway,
